# complete remove splash resource from cordova android build

Tags: android, cordova

For a small app, the splash resource files is too big, the generated apk file is about 5M, but If I remove splash files from platforms/android/res, the apk file will reduced to 700k, So my question is how to remove splash resource from cordova android build without delete the file manually?

And, I have set

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

in config.xml, but the splash files still in apk.

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove and add your android platform.

cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android

If it doesn't work, try to remove the plugin using:
cordova plugin remove NAME_OF_PLUGIN (I guess it is cordova-plugin-splashscreen)

and then do the steps above

Comment: cordova plugins --ls shows only cordova-plugin-whitelist

Answer (score 0):

To disable the splashscreen add the following preference to config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

AutoHideSplashScreen (boolean, default to true). Indicates whether to hide splash screen automatically or not. Splash screen hidden after amount of time specified in the SplashScreenDelay preference.

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
```